# Where to place validation code

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012

I've created a simple form with an enum field on a grid, dragged from the DataSource *CompanyImage*:

Table CompanyImage has an Index on this field named Brand in my example and AllowDuplicates is set to **No** :

[image]

And here is the form:

[image]

I've overridden the close() method of the form like this:

```
public void close()
{
    CompanyImage_ds.write();
    super();
}
```

An error is displayed when I close it saying that

"Cannot create a record in CompanyImage(CompanyImage). Legal entities: Example1.
The record already exists."

That's fine but I would like a way to stop closing the window when this happens. A `validateWrite()` would be nice but I am not really able to figure out where and what to write in order to accomplish this behavior.

I mean, how to check that new row is added and it contains a field that already exists in the table ?

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't have to force the write() method. Closing the form should already do it.

If you wish to check something to allow the form to be closed, the close() method is too late in execution. You should leverage the canClose() method.

Answer (score 0):

You could override the validate method of the grid column. You would need to write some validation logic in that method but that would prevent the column from saving at all if validation failed.

```
public boolean validate()
{
   boolean ret;
   // write your own validation logic
   if (validation logic is true)
   {
       ret = true;
   }

  return ret;

}
```